# Ruby beginner: class, instance variable, accessor, rspec

Tags: ruby, class, rspec, instance-variables, accessor

So I'm in the process of trying to recreate a board game called Ciao Ciao. I'm not anywhere near done but I keep getting stuck and would really appreciate some help. So far I've made the following 3 classes and rspec file:

The Player class

```
require_relative 'die'

class Player
attr_reader :name
attr_accessor :token, :position, :point

def initialize(name, token, position, point)
    @name = name
    @token = token
    @position = position
    @point = point
end

def advance
    @position += @number #basically I want the player to advance when he rolls between 1-4 but not sure how to connect it to the Die class here.
end

def lie
    @token -= 1 #here I want the player to lose a token if he rolls between 5-6
    @position == 0 #and have to start again from position 0
end

def score
    @token -= 1
    @position == 0
    @point += 1
end
end
```

The Game Class

```
require_relative 'player'
require_relative 'die'

class Game
def initialize(title)
    @title = title
    @players = []
end

def join(player)
    @players << player
end

def play
    puts "There are #{@players.size} players in the current round of #{@title}."
    @players.each do |player|
    die = Die.new
    case die.roll
    when 1..4
        puts "#{player.name} just rolled #{die.roll}!"
        player.advance
        puts "#{player.name} advances to #{player.position}!"
    when 5..6
        puts "#{player.name} just rolled #{die.roll}!"
        player.lie
        puts "#{player.name} is down to #{player.token} and starts at #{player.name}!"
    end

    puts "#{player.name} has #{player.point} points and is at #{player.position}. He has #{player.token} token(s) left."

    if player.position >= 10
        player.score
        puts "#{player.name} scores a point for reaching the endzone!"
    end

    if player.token == 0 
        @players.delete(player)
        puts "#{player.name} has been eliminated."
    end
    end
end
end
```

The Die Class

```
class Die
attr_reader :number

def initialize
end

def roll
    @number = rand(1..6)
end
end
```

The rspec file

```
require_relative 'game'

describe Game do
before do
    @game = Game.new("chaochao")

    @initial_token == 4
    @initial_position == 0
    @initial_point == 0
    @player = Player.new("iswg", @initial_token, @initial_position, @initial_point)

    @game.join(@player)
end

it "advances the player if a number between 1 and 4 is rolled" do
    @game.stub(:roll).and_return(3)
    @game.play
    @player.position.should == @initial_position + 3
end

it "makes the player lie if a number between 5 and 6 is rolled" do
    @game.stub(:roll).and_return(5)
    @game.play
    @player.token.should == @initial_token - 1
end
end
```

I keep getting the following error message when I run the rspec file:

Failures:

1) Game advances the player if a number between 1 and 4 is rolled
     Failure/Error: @game.play
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
     # ./player.rb:19:in`lie'
     # ./game.rb:24:in `block in play'
     # ./game.rb:16:in`each'
     # ./game.rb:16:in `play'
     # ./game_spec.rb:17:in`block (2 levels) in '

2) Game makes the player lie if a number between 5 and 6 is rolled
     Failure/Error: @game.play
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
     # ./player.rb:15:in`advance'
     # ./game.rb:21:in `block in play'
     # ./game.rb:16:in`each'
     # ./game.rb:16:in `play'
     # ./game_spec.rb:23:in`block (2 levels) in '

So the error message points to the advance/lie methods under Player class but I have no idea what I've done wrong. Also please feel free to point out other blunders. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Look at your example setup. Instead of initializing `@initial_token`, you're comparing it to 4. For better or worse, when you refer to an uninitialized instance variable, it always returns `nil` — thus, instead setting an instance variable, you're asking of nil equals some value and moving on.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the whole problem, but it's *a* problem.

Your first error stood out to me a bit.  `player.lie` is only supposed to be called when the roll is a 5 or 6, but you stubbed the roll method to return a 3.  Or did you?

`roll` is a method of the `Die` class, but you stubbed `@game`, which is an instance of the `Game` class.